# Baby Rudin 1.6 a. Alternate Proof

Tags: analysis

The proof I got for 1.6 a. in Baby Rudin is different from those I've seen elsewhere. I wonder if I made a mistake?

> 1.6: Fix $>1$.
> Prove that if $,,,$ are integers, $>0,>0$ and $=\frac{}{}=\frac{}{}$, then $(^)^{\frac{1}{}}=(^)^{\frac{1}{}}$

My attempt:

Since $=\frac{}{}=\frac{}{}$, then $mq = pn$

Therefore, $b^{mq} = b^{pn}$

So, $({b^m})^q = ({b^p})^n$

Therefore, $\bigl(({b^m})^q\bigr)^{\frac{1}{qn}} = \bigl(({b^p})^n\bigr)^{\frac{1}{qn}}$

So, $({b^m})^{\frac{1}{n}} = ({b^p})^{\frac{1}{q}}$

Comment: You use the fact that $(B^q)^{1/qn}=B^{1/n}$ in the last step, but the well posedness need to be proved by this exercise.

Comment: @LiufengYang Well I'm using the fact that $(b^p)^n)^{1/(qn)}$ = $(b^p)^{1/q}$, which doesn't seem to be an equivalent property.

Comment: Yes, the fact is weaker than the exercise and can be checked by definition easily, as $((B^q)^{1/qn})^{qn}=B^q=(B^{1/n})^{qn}\Rightarrow (B^q)^{1/qn}=B^{1/n}$. Combining with this, your proof might be more complete.

Comment: What is the definition of $b^{1/k}$ in Rudin?

Comment: @JustinYoung - Rudin does the most basic definition: $b^{1/k}$ is the unique positive real number such that $(b^{1/k})^k = b$.